# How does Fastapi manage concurrent calls to the database with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I want to understand how the database is still consistent after concurrent calls to the endpoint which update a counter. Sorry for the names of the classes/methods I copied most of the code from the docs of the tools.

The server code is as follow

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

app = FastAPI()

engine = create_engine('postgresql://postgres:test@localhost/test')
Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    counter = Column(Integer)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "counter='%s'" % (self.counter)


Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

# create
session = Session()
ed_user = User(name='ed', counter=0)
session.add(ed_user)
session.commit()
session.close()


async def updates():
    # update
    for i in range(50):
        session = Session()
        our_user = session.query(User).filter_by(name='ed').first()
        c = our_user.counter
        our_user.counter = c + 1
        session.add(our_user)
        session.commit()
        session.close()


@app.get("/update")
async def update():
    await updates()
    return {"Hello": "World"}


@app.get("/counter")
async def counter():
    session = Session()
    our_user = session.query(User).filter_by(name='ed').first()
    print(our_user)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

I start it and then run the following script:

```
from threading import Thread
import requests


def info():
    r = requests.get('http://localhost:8000/counter')


def thread():
    threads = []

    for _ in range(100):
        t = Thread(target=fetch())
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    for t in threads:
        t.join()


def fetch():
    requests.get("http://localhost:8000/update")


thread()
info()
```

The result of the counter at the end is always correct, even when using non-asnyc endpoints and `updates()` method. I tried doing the same without running Fastapi and only use Threads which run the `updates()` function, but in this case the counter is inconsistent.

So for some reason Fastapi does the magic, but what exactly is happening? And Shouldn't the database provide some kind of isolation feature, too?

**EDIT**

It was actually a bug in my code, where I didn't create the threads in a right way. I passed the result of `fetch()` instead of the function itself.
Now when I run it the rightway it behaves as expected and the non-async version has an **inconsistent** counter.

Comment: Have you read [Concurrency and async/await](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/async/) in the fastapi documentation? It explains really well how this works!

Comment: actually yes! But there was a bug in my code that made the non-async version consistent. The target of the threads wasn't a function but its result.

Comment: The question was how concurrent calls to async and non-asnyc endpoints lead to the same result, although in non-async there should be inconsistencies, due to access on same resource. But the cause of this behaviour was a bug in my example code, I fixed it and now it behaves as expected. So there is no more question.

Answer (score 0):

There was actually a bug in my example code. It should be

```
def thread():
    threads = []

    for _ in range(100):
        t = Thread(target=fetch)
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    for t in threads:
        t.join()
```

I passed the target parameter the result of the function not the function itself. That is why it didn't behave as expected and async and non-async endpoints showed the same results. Now it behaves as expected and the non-async endpoint shows inconsistent results, due to concurrent access on same resource.